# What is the ENGINE in OpenSSL and what is it used for?

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography, evp-cipher

I cannot find a good explanation of what the `ENGINE` in OpenSSL is. It is used in functions like `EVP_PKEY_CTX_new`.

I am using `EVP_PKEY_CTX_new` just before I encrypt/decrypt something using `EVP_PKEY_encrypt` and `EVP_PKEY_decrypt` but do I really need to specify the `ENGINE` parameter when calling `EVP_PKEY_CTX_new`. Everywhere I look inside the OpenSSL the parameter is specified as null.

So my question is:
What is the `ENGINE` in OpenSSL and what is it used for and what difference does it make when it is not specified?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The engine is the hardware or software implementation used for performing cryptographic operations. The default engine ID is `openssl` and uses the built-in functions of OpenSSL.

Assume we have a hardware device with a super fast implementation of AES. Now when we use AES encryption we can set the engine to that hardware device (instead of `NULL`), which means that the operations are now computed by the hardware device instead of the default OpenSSL software layer.

---

This is explained in Section 4.6 of the [Network Security with OpenSSL](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596002701.do) book.

> OpenSSL has built-in support for cryptographic acceleration. Using the
>   `ENGINE` object type, an application can get a reference to a
>   changeable, underlying representation, most often a hardware device.
>   (...)
>
> The general idea is simple: we retrieve an object representing the
>   type of hardware we wish to utilize, then we tell OpenSSL to use the
>   device we chose.
>
> *Example 4-17* shows a small code example of how we would perform this operation.
>
> ```
> ENGINE *e;
> if (!(e = ENGINE_by_id("cswift")))
>     fprintf(stderr, "Error finding specified ENGINE\n");
> else if (!ENGINE_set_default(e, ENGINE_METHOD_ALL))
>     fprintf(stderr, "Error using ENGINE\n");
> else
>     fprintf(stderr, "Engine successfully enabled\n");
> ```
>
> The function call `ENGINE_by_id` will look up an implementation from
>   the built-in methods available and return an `ENGINE` object. The
>   single argument to this function should be the string identifier of
>   the underlying implementation we wish to use. (...)
>
> The `ENGINE` object that we receive from the lookup should be used in
>   the call to `ENGINE_set_default` to allow cryptographic functions to
>   utilize the capabilities of the specific `ENGINE`. The second
>   parameter allows us to specify constraints on what we allow the engine
>   to implement. (...)

NOTE: `cswift` is "used for CryptoSwift" acceleration hardware."

Comment: Link to book outdated.

Comment: "Link to book outdated." – I quoted the most relevant part of the book under the fair use doctrine. (Initially, I wasn't going to add the last two paragraphs. I hope I didn't quote too much.) The book costs like 30 bucks new, or 10 used; and is easily found in a library.